# PHP compare associative arrays by specific value

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, laravel-4

I'm running 2 databases, SQL and Mongo and when I query them for the model I need, I cast it to arrays.

```
$sql = [1 => ["id" => 1, "num" => "123"], 2 => ["id" => 2, "num" => "456"]];
$mongo = ["id" => 1, "num" => "123"];
```

But sometime I get multi arrays and sometime I can get just 1 array.

I'd like to compare both arrays by `"num"` value and remove the difference array (with id 2)...

I expect to get an associative arrays of the difference:

```
$result = [1 => ["id" => 2, "num" => "456"]];
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please provide an expected output of your comparison.

Comment: You can simply do a foreach on $sql array and remove the values with $mongo['num'] == $sql_item['num'] but maybe i don't have understand the question properly

Answer (score 0):

Naively I would try something like this (the comparison should be optimized if needed):

```
$sql = (isset($sql['id']) ? array(1 => $sql) : $sql; // Always make multi-dimensionnal array
$mongo = (isset($mongo['id']) ? array(1 => $mongo) : $mongo; // Always make multi-dimensionnal array

$results = array();
foreach($sql as $sq)
    foreach($mongo as $mq)
        if ($sq['num'] != $mq['num'])
             $results[] = $mq;
```

Edit: a better solution using php function [`array_udiff`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-udiff.php)

```
$sql = (isset($sql['id']) ? array(1 => $sql) : $sql; // Always make multi-dimensionnal array
$mongo = (isset($mongo['id']) ? array(1 => $mongo) : $mongo; // Always make multi-dimensionnal array

$results = array_udiff($sql, $mongo, function($a, $b) { return $a['num'] - $b['num']; });
```